# How do I save a buttons image state in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I have this like button and when the user pressed on it the image changed to another image. How would I be able to save the new image when I close my app and open it up again. I have the code below and Im using NSUserDefaults but its not saving the changed image. Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Change")

}

     @IBAction func addToLikes(_ sender: Any) {
    //progressView.isHidden = false

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Change") {
         likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)
    } 
    }
```

Comment: if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Change") {
         likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)
    }

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "starSelected") {
    likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)
        print("star selected")
    }

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "starNotSelected") {
    likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "not_selected_star"), for: .normal)
        print("star not selected")

    }

        }

}

 @IBAction func addToLikes(_ sender: Any) {
//progressView.isHidden = false

        likedButton.isSelected = !likedButton.isSelected

    if likedButton.isSelected {
            print("I am selected.")
            likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_star"), for: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "starNotSelected")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "starSelected")

    } else {
            likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "not_selected_star"), for: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "starSelected")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "starNotSelected")

            print("I am not selected.")
    }
```

Comment: This won’t allow you to toggle its state

Comment: Do keep in mind when app goes to background and also is there a different button for disliking ?

Comment: @xcode22 Bool has a mutating method called toggle exactly for this purpose `likedButton.isSelected.toggle()`

Comment: Why don't you use a single key ? `UserDefaults.standard.set(likedButton.isSelected, forKey: "isSelected")`

Comment: `likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: likedButton.isSelected ? "selected_star" : "not_selected_star")`

Comment: and remove the if condition

Comment: the same for viewDidLoad `likedButton.setImage(UIImage(named: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSelected") ? "selected_star" : "not_selected_star"), for: .normal)`

Comment: Going to try that. Thanks!